# How to select a few table fields and all of another table like `t1.field, t2.*`

Tags: sql, 4d-database

Does anyone know if a one can query a 4D database selecting all of a particular table like one can do in MySQL? I haven't been able to find any documentation on it.

### Fails

I've tried this query but it fails to parse `Syntax error: 1301 Failed to parse statement.`

```
SELECT c.Customer_Name, p.*
FROM Customer c
JOIN EOE_EDI_Partner p ON p.BillTo_Customer_ID = c.Customer_ID
```

### Works

This works, but gets data from both tables

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer c
JOIN EOE_EDI_Partner p ON p.BillTo_Customer_ID = c.Customer_ID
```

And I'd like to refrain from writing out each field in the desired table (its a lot)

```
SELECT p.Name, p.ID, p.FieldName, p.......
FROM Customer c
JOIN EOE_EDI_Partner p ON p.BillTo_Customer_ID = c.Customer_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The doc ( [4D SQL Reference: SELECT](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv17/4D/17/SELECT.300-3786789.en.html) ) says it's not possible:

> Queries with mixed "*" and explicit fields are not allowed.

They suggest to use * to have all field from both tables (as you made in you first working example) that is:

```
SELECT * FROM t1, t2
```

Also you cannot use a subquery instead of t1, I verified it.

Comment: Add description here